# How write subfactories linked to their general factory (avoiding these subfactories to be linked to another factories)?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I program in Java with the Spring Framework.
But i have a question about design pattern.

I have a class X with 3 parts, 3 "big" parts:
A
B
C

```
class X {
   private A a;
   private B b;
   private C c;
   // getters and setters
}
```

I make a factory for this class with 3 big privates methods to construct the 3 parts of the object of type X.

```
@Service
class XFactoryImpl implements XFactory {

    @Override
    X createX(InputData inputData) {
       X x = new X();
       x.setA(createA(inputData);
       x.setB(createB(inputData);
       x.setC(createC(inputData);
       return x;
    }

    private A createA(InputData inputData) {
       A a = new A();
       // lot of code lines
      return a;
    }

    private B createB(InputData inputData) {
       B b = new B();
       // lot of code lines
       return b;
    }

    private C createC(InputData inputData) {
       C c = new C();
       // lot of code lines
      return c;
    }

}
```

The problem is the following :
as the 3 private methods createA, createB and createC are big methods,
the factory implementation class is very big.

One solution could be to create 3 "subfactories" and inject these 3 subfactories into class FactoryX, one for class A objects, one for class B objects, one for C objects.

But the class A has no meaning outside of class X : A is necessary a type attribute of a class X object.
Idem for class B and class C.

**I** **do** **not** **want** **to** **create** **a** **Factory** **for** **objects** **of** **class** **A** **without** **linking** **this** **factory** **to** **Factory** **X** **class X**, **and** **especially** **forbid** **the** **calling** **of** **this** **factoryA** **outside** **from** **the** **factoryX** (because calling this FactoryA NOT to create an object of class X has absolutely no sense, no meaning as A is only in my project a type of an attribute of class X).

**I want to forbid to inject FactoryAImpl instance outside from FactoryX class but i do not find the solution now.**

**If** **i** **create** **a** **factory** **for** **class** **A**, **is** **it** **possible** **to** **link** **it** **absolutely** **with** **class** **X** **?**
**If** **yes,** **how** **please** **?**
**If** **not,** **which** **design** **pattern** **could** **i** **use** **?**

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to forbid FactoryA to be instanced outside the FactoryX, encapsulate it to package-private.

```
class FactoryA{ // don't use public modifier so it only be accessed from the same package.
    FactoryA(){ } // don't use public modifier, so it only be instantiated from class in the same package
}
```

Make sure to put FactoryA and FactoryX in the same package directory.

Comment: Thank you very much Ferry.As you say, i will create a dedicated package for FactoryX and all its subfactories.  Thank you very much my friend.